# Looking for a Html Date range similar to Google Flights

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a date range that is similar to the date range selector from the new [Google Flights](http://www.google.com/flights/) site.

I am not interested in the price part, but mostly is the ease of use for selecting the start to end of the range.

Does a similar javascript control exists?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google invented it. They may have open-sourced the JavaScript for it, but I would imagine not, since it's the slickest date UI on the web since sliced bread.